# Mapbox: It renders the last point instead of all

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to render multiple points using Mapbox but it only displays the last one. I've added the feature parameter but nothing. This should render the two markers but i don't know why it doesn't. I'm not getting any errors in the console.

I'm stuck and can't find a way to solve it. Help?

This is the code responsible for the points.:

```
map.on('load', function() {
    map.loadImage('images/celltower.png', function(error, image) {
        if (error) throw error;
        map.addImage('tower', image);
        map.addLayer({
            "id": "points",
            "type": "symbol",
            "source": {
                "type": "geojson",
                "data": {
                    "type": "FeatureCollection",
                    "features": [{
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [21.42559803007430, 42.00038270989050]
                        },
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [21.38529272846381, 42.0080397578202]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "layout": {
                "icon-image": "tower",
                "icon-size": 0.25
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a duplicate `geometry` key. Judging by the fact that `features` is an array, I would guess this is the proper way to do it:

```
map.on('load', function() {
    map.loadImage('images/celltower.png', function(error, image) {
        if (error) throw error;
        map.addImage('tower', image);
        map.addLayer({
            "id": "points",
            "type": "symbol",
            "source": {
                "type": "geojson",
                "data": {
                    "type": "FeatureCollection",
                    "features": [{
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [21.42559803007430, 42.00038270989050]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [21.38529272846381, 42.0080397578202]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "layout": {
                "icon-image": "tower",
                "icon-size": 0.25
            }
        });
    });
});
```

According to the [GeoJSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.3), there should be a way to specify multiple points. E.g.:

```
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPoint",
        "coordinates": [
            [21.42559803007430, 42.00038270989050],
            [21.38529272846381, 42.0080397578202]
        ]
    }
}]
```

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thank you very much :) You are a life saver